# [RegEx]Regular expression for a number greater than 10000

Tags: regex, shell, grep

I am using zgrep to find some strings which contain numbers greater than 10000. I tried

```
zgrep '[1-9]\d{4}' (filename here)
```

But nothing is returned.
Anyone who could tell me the correct usage with explanation will be appreciated greatly.

Comment: `\d` character class isn't supported by grep (and probably zgrep). Use `[0-9]` instead. Search about the BRE syntax. The curly brackets for the quantifier in BRE syntax are escaped `{4}` => `\{4\}`

Comment: I tried `zgrep '[1-9][0-9]{4}'`. But still got nothing. I am sure there are some numbers greater than 50000 in the file.

Comment: update the page to see the end of my previous comment.

Comment: Try: `zgrep -E '[1-9][0-9]{4}' file`

Comment: It works. Thank you very much!!

Comment: I tried Casimir et Hippolyte's solution. It works. Also thank you all the others who proposed answers. I appreciate!

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the "-P" flag in your zgrep command.

```
zgrep -P '[1-9]\d{4}'
```

The "\d" is used in a [Perl Regular Expression](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_regular_expression.htm). Without the "-P" flag you're using a [Basic Regular Expression](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ugrep.htm#Extended-Regexp). With a "-E" flag you're using a [Extended Regular Expression](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ugrep.htm#Extended-Regexp).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation